# How can you display a blinking cursor?

Tags: javascript, cursor

I'm thinking about writing a full screen HTML/CSS/JavaScript editor for the browser so that a user can write their programs directly to the server without having to do the Dreamweaver local view/remote server Dosey Doe. I would need to display a cursor just like what you see in a normal textarea or an input field.

Q: How can you display a blinking cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `contenteditable` on your HTML element. Clicking inside any element with that attribute will give the system's default blinking cursor.

```
<div contenteditable>
  The content in this DIV is editable and clicking on it will show a blinking cursor.
</div>
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable